# Insert date values into SQL datetime column from excel

Tags: sql, excel, import

I am trying to insert data from excel to a SQL table.

When I try to insert date values into the datetime column the values are being taken as null.

Can anyone help here.

Comment: hi kiran, please edit your question to include your code and then folks may be able to help. You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You probaby need to change the date format to match the date format id the database, but more info will be needed.